# PhantomJS is not able to find the element with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, chutzpah

I have a Selenium web-driver Script Which just accesses a web-element(textbox) and sets its value to some value .

I am using ChutzPath because it uses PhantomJS browser on back-end.

But Every time execute the script,The following error is displayed.

```
T
Result Message: 
Test method Test_Project_with_Selenium.UnitTest1.BrowseTheWeb threw exception: 

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with id 'inputEl''
 ***caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"47","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:42982"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"textfield-1042-inputEl\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/01225660-1a45-11e3-8ea4-eff85782779d/element"}
Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at Test_Project_with_Selenium.UnitTest1.BrowseTheWebClient() in c:\Users\XYZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectName\Test_Project_with_Selenium\UnitTest1.cs:line 19***
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the HTML.  Off the cuff, you probably are having an issue where the element loads after Selenium queries the page (and you could use implicit waits for the element you want to appear - driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));.) Or the id you are looking for is inside of a frame/iframe, in which case you would need to use Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameIdentifier");

Comment: @Richard, go ahead and put that in an answer.  You are spot on.

Comment: It's important to show use (the relevant parts of) your script as well, so we can actually see your code and look for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the case here, since the question is not very specific, but one thing I ran into is that PhantomJS 1.9.7 requires the HTTP scheme in the location.

So, if you are navigating `localhost:42982/element`, you should specify to the driver that you want to navigate to `http://localhost:42982/element`.

Comment: Thanks Artjom. Edited to specify that I'm on 1.9.7 (1.1.0 was to https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver )

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, you probably are having an issue where the element loads after Selenium queries the page, and you could use waitfor.js

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

Or possibly this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Or the id you are looking for is inside of a frame/iframe, in which case you would need to use

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameIdentifier");
```